# Display row in mysql table when a user enter id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display a row when a user enter his id and after submit.
My code is not working correctly. Please rectify this.

search-form.php is looking like this.

```
</html><body>
 <form method="GET" action="search.php">
  Keyfield <input type="text" name="search"> <br><br>
  <input type="submit"  value="submit">
</form></body>
</html>
```

and

search.php looking like this.

```
<?php

$connection =     mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass')     or die ("Couldn't connect to server."); 
$db = mysql_select_db('db', $connection) or die ("Couldn't select     database."); 

$search=$_GET['search'];

$fetch = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ID` = "'.$search.'"'; 
  echo "<table margin=auto width=999px border=1>";
        echo "<tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Telephone</b></td><td>    <b>E-mail</b></td><td><b>Couttry Applying for</b></td><td><b>Visa-Category</b>    </td><td><b>Other Category</b></td><td><b>Passport No</b></td><td>    <b>Remarks</b></td></tr>";
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
    {
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($fetch);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[2]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[3]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[4]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[5]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[6]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[7]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[8]</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
    }//for
    echo"</table>";
?>
```

Display when a user enter his id and submit. But this code doesn't display row with id.
Rectify this.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't ever execute the query

Answer (score 0):

you are missing mysql_query statement.You should execute the query before fetching the result
modify like
    $sql= 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ID` = "'.$search.'"'; 
    $fetch = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: also modify your for loop .$num would be unknown

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. mysql_connect is obsolete, do not use it. Use PDO instead for example.
2. `$fetch = 'SELECT * FROM`table`WHERE`ID`= "'.$search.'"'` leads to the most common and severe security flaw : SQL injection. Please read about this (google)
3. Where do you "fetch" the result of your query ?

About point 3, assuming the fact that you will use PDO, please read http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html